# React (Unit & Integration): Which framework to use for react unit testing and Integration testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have just started with development in Reactjs. I am looking for testing framework(Javascript). Which can be used to do both "Unit Testing", "Integration Testing" and "e2e testing".

Please, help me if we can do the the required testing using Javascript.

Comment: i propose jest build by facebook also (https://jestjs.io/)

Answer (score 1):

You should try enzyme for unit testing and cypress for e2e tests

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/
https://www.cypress.io/

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no one answer to you question. Because, there are so many testing framework mushrooming day-in-and-day-out, everyday.

To answer your query at best --

## By definition

**Unit Testing** — Unit testing helps to check that individual unit of code (mostly functions) work as expected.

**Integration Tests** — Integration tests are tests where individual units/features of the app are combined and tested as a group.

**End-to-End Tests** — This test helps to confirm that entire features work from the user’s perspective when using the actual application.

In this light, at our enterprise application that we've been building on [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org), in order to facilitate **Test Driven Development (TDD) approach**, we have been using [Jest](http://jestjs.io) - which is also supported by `facebook` (alongside it's *snapshot* testing feature) and [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) for different forms of *frontend* testing.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Jest.. Pretty amazing..